# TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT in Scala on Android ends as compiler error

Tags: android, scala

I'm translating the following Java code to Scala.

```
some_android_view.setLayoutParams(
    new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But it gives me the following compile error:

> value WRAP_CONTENT is not a member of object 
>        android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams

**EDIT**

replaced

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

for

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: I have tried using '#', but is still not compiling. I'm using scala 2.9. I get the following error: 

    object LayoutParams is not a 
      value
     - ')' expected but '#' found.
     - ')' expected but '#' found.

Comment: Sorry, that I'm confusing you, '#' it just link from my IDEA =) Please, use direct link to ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT constant.

Comment: This worked: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT. Thanks!. Edited the question.